# Satisfying the Rust borrow checker with structs

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to learn Rust, and as you can imagine, the borrow checker is my biggest adversary. So here's my setup, it's a kind of crate for the game battleship. The game is based on the `Battlefield` struct, which consists of `Cell`s. A `Cell` can reference a `Ship` and a `Ship` has a vector of all `Cell`s it's referenced by, so it's a bi-directional read-only relationship.

```
pub struct Battlefield<'a> {
    cells: Vec<Vec<Cell<'a>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Cell<'a> {
    ship: Option<&'a Ship<'a>>
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Ship<'a> {
    length: usize,
    cells: Vec<&'a Cell<'a>>,
}
```

My problem is `Battlefield`'s `place_ship` function:

```
impl<'a> Battlefield<'a> {
    pub fn place_ship(&mut self,
                      ship: &'a mut Ship,
                      x: usize,
                      y: usize,
                      orientation: Orientation)
                      -> PlaceResult {
        // check ship placement in bounds
        // check affected cells are free
        // set cells' ship ref to ship
        // add cell refs to ship's cells field
    }
}
```

It makes sense to me and I don't think there's an ownership problem here, but I'm wrong it seems:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{Battlefield, X, Y};
    use super::Orientation::*;
    use super::super::ship::Ship;

    #[test]
    fn assert_ship_placement_only_in_bounds() {
        let mut ship = Ship::new(3);
        let mut bf = Battlefield::new();

        assert_eq!(Ok(()), bf.place_ship(&mut ship, 0, 0, Horizontal));
        assert_eq!(Ok(()), bf.place_ship(&mut ship, 5, 5, Vertical));
    }
}
```

```
src/battlefield.rs:166:47: 166:51 error: cannot borrow `ship` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
src/battlefield.rs:166         assert_eq!(Ok(()), bf.place_ship(&mut ship, 5, 5, Vertical));
                                                                 ^~~~
src/battlefield.rs:165:47: 165:51 note: first mutable borrow occurs here
src/battlefield.rs:165         assert_eq!(Ok(()), bf.place_ship(&mut ship, 0, 0, Horizontal));
                                                                 ^~~~
```

I know this is just a short excerpt, but the whole code is too much to post here. The [project can be found here](https://github.com/Leopard2A5/lib-battleship/tree/experiment) (standard build with 'cargo build').

Comment: *but the whole code is too much to post here* — I **guarantee** that you can make the code small enough to post here while still reproducing the same error. See [MCVE].

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423; maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/20698384/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/28833622/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/29893978/155423. Or any question about mutable aliasing. [Like the error says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0499), you cannot borrow **anything** as mutable more than once at a time.

Comment: "bi-directional" - "I don't think there's an ownership problem" - There's always an ownership problem once you've got bidirectional relationships.

Comment: @SebastianRedl why thank you for this constructive comment. Good thing you remembered to keep the "read-only" out of your quote...! I may be a noob when it comes to rust, but a non-mut ref has nothing to do with ownership.

Comment: @Leopard2A5 References, mut or non-mut, affect ownership exactly the same way: the owner must keep the object alive until the references are gone. Mut or non-mut just influences what other references may be taken. Yes, mut references make bi-directional even more difficult because of aliasing issues, but Rust makes any kind of bi-directional relationship difficult. Just look at how tricky it is to implement a doubly linked list. The bottom line is that in Rust, it is very often the best choice to redesign until the bi-directional relationships are gone.

Comment: @SebastianRedl and why not just *explain* it to me like this in the first place? why make your first comment sound condescending? Anyways, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

From the signature of `Battlefield::place_ship`, the compiler must suppose that the function may store a mutable reference to `ship` in `self` (the `Battlefield<'a>` object). That's because you're linking the lifetime of the `ship` parameter with the lifetime parameter of `Battlefield`, and the compiler only looks at the high-level interface of a struct, so that all structs that look the same behave the same (otherwise, adding a field to a struct, even if all fields are private, might be a breaking change!).

If you change the declaration of `ship` from `ship: &'a mut Ship` to `ship: &mut Ship<'a>`, you'll see that the error goes away (if the method's body does nothing with the parameter). However, if you try to store a copy of this pointer in `Cell`'s `ship` field, this will no longer work, as now the compiler cannot prove that the `Ship` will live long enough.

You'll keep running into issues with lifetimes, because what you're trying to do will not work with simple references. Right now, there's a contradiction in your definitions of `Battlefield`, `Cell` and `Ship`: you're declaring that `Battlefield` holds `Cell`s who references `Ship`s that outlive the `Battlefield`. However, at the same time, you're declaring that `Ship` references `Cell`s that outlive the `Ship`. The only way this will work is if you declare the `Battlefield` and the `Ship`s **on the same `let` statement** (as the compiler will assign the same lifetime to all values).

```
let (mut ship, mut bf) = (Ship::new(3), Battlefield::new());
```

You'll also need to change `&mut self` to `&'a mut self` to assign a `Cell` from `self` to a `Ship`. But then as soon as you call `place_ship`, you'll effectively end up locking the `Battlefield`, as the compiler will suppose that the `Battlefield` may store a mutable reference to itself (which it can because it takes a mutable reference to itself as a parameter!).

A better approach would be to use [reference counting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) instead of simple references combined with [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) instead of explicit mutability. Reference counting means that you won't have to deal with lifetimes (though here's you'd have to break cycles with [weak pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) in order to avoid memory leaks). Interior mutability means that you can pass immutable references instead of mutable references; this will avoid `cannot borrow x as mutable more than once` compiler errors since there will be no mutable borrows at all.

Comment: IMO, the "better" (but differently structured) solution is to not let child components have references to parent structures, but instead to only pass down the parent reference when needed by a specific child method.

Comment: @Shepmaster I want to store a ref to the cells in the ship in order to easily find out if all cells of a ship have been hit. But you can see i come from a garbage-collected background :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Francis! I can't say that i fully understand it on the first read :) I see i still have a lot to learn about rust.

Comment: @Leopard2A5 if you have some method `impl Ship { fn all_were_hit(&self) -> bool {} }`, try changing it to `impl Ship { fn all_were_hit(&self, &Battlefield) -> bool {} }` (or whatever types are appropriate) and see how it goes.